# How to center WPF CheckBox within GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to center WPF CheckBox within  GridViewColumn?

```
<GridViewColumn   Width="60" Header="Success">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSuccess}">                                                  
              </CheckBox>
          </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

---

UPDATES:

This solution works fine but it destroys Expression Dark theme for cells...
(I don't know for know how to fix it...)

```
<ListView Name="HistoryTable" Width="783" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Height="195">
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="DataGridCheckBox">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}},Path=ActualWidth}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.Resources>
                            <ListView.View>                                     
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Filename}" Width="140" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Name, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn   Width="60" Header="{lex:LocTextExtension Key=Success, Dict=Resources, Assembly=PreShow.Player}">
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSuccess}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBox}">                                                  
                                                    </CheckBox>
                                                 </DockPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, i was confusing things here. I've deleted the answer. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: follow the answer by H.B. - you're missing the BasedOn property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be the bare-bone setup:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <!-- Alternatively use the ItemContainerStyle of course -->
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- Use BasedOn to preserve existing style -->
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: You solution works but destroys Expression Dark Theme. I am going to update my post to put screenshot what happens.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: You could not have guessed to add a `BasedOn` to the `ListViewItem` as well?

Comment: I am not a big master of WPF :)  Please tell where I have to add it for Expression Dark Theme?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: I already changed the code, and you should **not** just copy and paste code from StackOverflow, read [the documentation of the things mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) and **understand how things work**.

Comment: Thank you! I've studied a lot from you code always! Everything is cool!

Answer (score 10):

Bind a new Grid's column width (in the DataTemplate) to that of the GridView's column width.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Header="{StaticResource CheckBoxHeaderText}" x:Name="CheckBoxColumn" Width="125">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxColumn, Path=Width}">
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```